# jquery flip! background

Tags: jquery, background, flip

I'm using the Flip Plugin on a new site I'm making:

http://www.concept-it.be/padre (click on contact and then on the e-mail address).

As you can see the background of the div becomes gray after when the flip starts and it stay's like this. I don't mind having it like that when flipping but after the flip I want my backgroundimage back.

I've tried the following:

setting removeAttr on my flipping div after the animation with the option onEnd

setting removeAttr just below the flipping function

setting the content to `<div style="background: url("../images/black.png")"></div>`

but that doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time the color option has been added.

Example:

```
$('.item-to-flip').click(function() {
    $(this).flip({
        direction:'tb',
        color:'#1F1F1F'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please provide a link to the plugin.

im going to assume that the plugin has a callback function

inside of the callback you could try
$('#contactform').removeAttr('background-color').css('background-image', 'url("../images/black.png")');

Comment: I'm not using it anymore for the moment. I also got the following answer from the creator of the script:

Hi Dante,
actually is not possible to avoid the "background-color" because of the technique my plugin is using.
What you can do right now is set the bgColor param to the color your prefer (default is #999).